# TypeError in view: Field expected a number but got SimpleLazyObject

Tags: django, django-views, django-3.1

I upgraded to django v3.1 and suddenly getting this error:

> Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: '23'>.

The failing line of code is this:

```
my_obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling around I found this [post by Aaron O. Ellis](https://groupthink.aaronoellis.com/articles/fixing-simplelazyobject-errors-in-django-3-1).

The trick is not to use the `kwargs` directly but from the view class with `self`:

```
my_obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Hope this helps anybody else as well.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you add a *minimal explanation* regarding the issue and the answer.

Comment: True, but I thought everybody who's looking for a quick fix will take it here and the ones looking for an explanation can go to the link, can't they?

Comment: Yep, But, as a devil's advocate, I would argue that the link may expire in future :P